# Is Samadhi mentioned in Jhana Suttas?

Tags: pali-canon, jhana, meditation-effects, samadhi

Do the Pali texts on jhana actually mention Samadhi and/or One-Pointedness by name in the jhana descriptions or is this mention apocryphal?

Answer (score 2):

The terms 'jhana', 'samadhi' & 'one-pointedness' ('ekaggataṃ') are all found in the sutta passage below:

> And what is the faculty of **concentration**? Katamañca, bhikkhave,
> **samādhi**ndriyaṃ?
>
> It’s when a noble disciple, relying on letting go, gains **concentration**,
> gains **unification of mind**. Idha, bhikkhave, ariyasāvako
> vossaggārammaṇaṃ karitvā labhati **samādhi**ṃ, labhati **cittassa**
> **ekaggataṃ**.
>
> Quite secluded from sensual pleasures, secluded from unskillful
> qualities, they enter and remain in the first **absorption**... So
> vivicceva kāmehi vivicca akusalehi dhammehi savitakkaṃ savicāraṃ
> vivekajaṃ pītisukhaṃ paṭhamaṃ **jhānaṃ** upasampajja viharati.
>
> [SN 48.10](https://suttacentral.net/sn48.10/en/sujato)

Comment: perfect - this important term is in there too - samādhindriyaṃ - this should settle all debates on the subject

Answer (score 1):

From SN 40.1:

> Then, friends, the Blessed One came to me by means of spiritual power and said this: ‘Moggallāna, Moggallāna, do not be negligent, brahmin, regarding the first jhāna. Steady your mind in the first jhāna, unify your mind in the first jhāna, concentrate your mind in the first jhāna.’ Then, friends, on a later occasion, secluded from sensual pleasures, secluded from unwholesome states, I entered and dwelt in the first jhāna, which is accompanied by thought and examination, with rapture and happiness born of seclusion."

Comment: I appreciate that he is asking that one trains in the first jhana, not the fourth! Thank you